# The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledbconnection, oledbexception

Data needs to be read into .net gridview from excel worksheet.
Here are the aspx and aspx.cs codes.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Read and Display Data From an Excel File (.xsl or .xlsx) in ASP.NET</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<b>Please Select Excel File: </b>
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadExcel" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import Data" OnClick="btnImport_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#009933"></asp:Label><br />
<asp:GridView ID="grvExcelData" runat="server">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASPX.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = "";
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(fileuploadExcel.FileName).ToLower();
    string path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;
    //Connection String to Excel Workbook
    if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path +";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2;\"";
    }

    string query = "SELECT [UserName],[Education],[Location] FROM [Sheet1$]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    grvExcelData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    grvExcelData.DataBind();
    da.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

conn.Open(); gives the following error:

> *The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you
>   need permission to view and write its data.*

Network service has been provided all the permissions for the folder in which the excel sheet is stored.

Comment: This means that the file hasn't finished uploading yet, or at least the server hasn't released it yet. The `Click` event and the upload happen in response to the same `POST` request from the browser

Comment: It doesn't help much. Can you tell me what I need to do in order to make it run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the uploaded file to a disk location with [FileUpload.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) before trying to process it. As the docs warn,

> The FileUpload control does not automatically save a file to the server ...

Files are cached in memory or a temporary folder on disk until you save them.

You should probably consider using a different method of processing Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (for xlsx), [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) (xls and xlsx) or just the Open XML SDK (xlsx). They don't need the Jet driver, have less quirks and some of the can read a stream directly.

This would allow you to read the uploaded contents directly from the uploaded file's `InputStream` property. Using [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc823095%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for example, you can write:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument =
SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.InputStream, false))
{
    ...
}
```